# Linux Files Management

Tags: c, linux

I'm learning Linux and I need to make a function that allows me to input redirection (stdin)and output redirection (stdout). I discovered one example where a file text with the name I chose to call it is actually created. But I don't understand how I can write to that same file after I create it. The function I discovered is the following one

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LOCKFILE "/etc/ptmp"
int main()
{
    int pfd;
    char filename[1024];
    if ((pfd = open("Test", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Cannot open output file\n"); exit(1);
    }
}
```

I need to create a function that allows me to input redirection (stdin)and output redirection (stdout) using open and also dup/dup2 but I'm searching all over the place and I can't find one answer that I really understand.

So now I'm trying this way but I can't still write to the file

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LOCKFILE "/etc/ptmp"
int main()
{
    int pfd;
    char filename[1024];
    if ((pfd = open("Test", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Cannot open output file\n"); exit(1);
    }
    dup2(STDIN_FILENO, pfd);
    close(pfd);
    printf("This will be put in the file\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `freopen("mystdout.txt", "a+", stdout);` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/ "[...] This function is especially useful for redirecting predefined streams like stdin, stdout and stderr to specific files (see the example below)."

Comment: I can only use open and dup/dup2. So I think that I can't use freopen but I think I understand the idea behind your answer

Answer (score 0):

After you open the file, you can redirect a standard file descriptor to it using `dup2()`:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LOCKFILE "/etc/ptmp"
int main()
{
    int pfd;
    char filename[1024];
    if ((pfd = open("Test", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Cannot open output file\n"); exit(1);
    }
    dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, pfd);
    close(pfd);
    printf("This will be put in the file\n");
    return 0;
}
```

To redirect `stdin` open the file in `O_RDONLY` mode and use `STDIN_FILENO`.

Comment: I tested it and the only new thing its the printf in the screen. I can write into a file by using --> dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, pfd) ?

Comment: Yes, that should redirect stdout to the file.

Comment: `dup2` duplicates a file descriptor to another one, so it "duplicates to (dup2)". Bizarre semantic.

Comment: Yes, but it would not be the standard output. Therefore, it would not follow the linux convention that allows to pipe processes together.

Comment: So if I understand I just can't directly write into a file when I'm creating it?

Comment: Creating and writing to files are separate operations. You can't do them both at the same time.

Comment: Oh now I understood! And after I create the file I can simply write to it from the terminal or I can create another function to make that?

Comment: You don't write to it from the terminal, the program writes to it after redirecting stdout.

Comment: But what makes me feel confused is how can I access stdout and where can I write to effectively write to the file?

Comment: `stdout` is used automatically by `printf()`.

Comment: `printf(...)` is equivalent to `fprintf(stdout, ...)`